# What are "unbounded loss functions" and "unbounded operators"?

Tags: vqe, machine-learning, terminology-and-notation, neural-network, quantum-neural-network

I am reading this paper: [Quantum Generative Training Using Rényi Divergences](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.09567.pdf). In it, the authors mention the following multiple times:

> "...an unbounded loss function can circumvent the existing no-go results"

> "...unbounded loss functions, such as the quantum relative entropy..."

> "...unbounded loss function such as maximal Rényi divergence of order two..."

> "...other unbounded loss functions such as relative entropy..."

> "...entanglement between the hidden and visible layers can still destroy the ability to train the network with respect to the bounded loss function..."

I have no clue what they mean by "unbounded/bounded loss function" here. At one point, they also say:

> "Existing algorithms almost exclusively utilize a **linear bounded operator** as a loss function. This condition is quite reasonable because the loss function is typically estimated by measuring the expectation values of Hermitian operators"

I am not sure if this usage of "linear bounded operator" is related; if not, what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, I think that the authors simply refer to a [bounded function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_function)

A linear operator is called [*bounded*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator) when it it has finite [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm). This is equivalent to saying that the linear operator is continuous as a map between normed vector spaces. Note that any linear operator on a *finite-dimensional* vector space is always bounded, so this is only a non-redundant concept if one is dealing with infinite-dimensional vector spaces.

Finally, if you define a function on states as $f(\rho) = \mathrm{tr}(A\rho)$ and $A$ is a bounded operator (on a Hilbert space), then this function is automatically bounded since we have by Hölder's inequality
$$
|f(\rho)| \leq \|A\|_\infty \|\rho\|_1 = \|A\|_\infty < \infty,
$$
where $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ is the operator/spectral norm and $\|\cdot\|_1$ is the trace norm.

PS: You could have answered this yourself by mere googling.